# Random variable $X$ has exponetial distribution with parameter $1$. What's the probability of $p(X\leq2)$

Tags: probability

Random variable $X$ has exponetial distribution with parameter $1$. What's the probability of $p(X\leq2)$

How can I calculate P(X=1) etc? Do I have to get aid from Poisson distribution like this:

$P(X=k)=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-k}$

$P(X=0)=\frac{1^0}{0!}e^{-1}=\frac{1}{e}$

$P(X=1)=\frac{1^1}{1!}e^{-1}=\frac{1}{e}$

$P(X=2)=\frac{1^2}{2!}e^{-1}=\frac{1}{2e}$

$P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)=\frac{5}{2e}$

Does it make sense?

Comment: A continuous random variable (such as exponential) has zero probability to have an exact value, so $\Pr(X=1)=0$. There are non-zero probabilities only to segments of the type $\Pr(a<X<b)$ (or $\leq$).

Comment: @YJT
So I have to use intergrals like this? For example $P(X\leq 5)=\int_{0}^{5}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$.
How about greater? $P(X\geq2)=\int_{2}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$? Between $P(2\leq X \leq 4)=\int_{2}^{4}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$

Comment: Yes. Or use CDF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An exponential variable is absolutely continuous and thus have a [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) which is a function $f$ that can be used to define the probability that the variable lies in an interval:

$$
\mathbb P(a \leq X \leq b ) = \int_a^b f(x)dx
$$

For absolutely continuous variable, it is more relevant to compute the probability of the variable falling in a given interval rather than computing the probability of the variable being equal to a number because $\mathbb P(X=x)=0$ for any real number $x$.

In the case of an exponential variable with a parameter $\lambda$ we have $f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} I_{x \geq 0}$.

Thus,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X \leq 2 ) &= \lim_{x \to -\infty} \mathbb P(x \leq X \leq 2) \\
&=  \lim_{x \to -\infty} \int_x^2 \lambda e^{-\lambda x} I_{x \geq 0}  dx\\
&= \int_{- \infty}^2  \lambda e^{-\lambda x} I_{x \geq 0} dx \\
&= \int_0^2  \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx \\
&= \lambda \left [ \frac{-1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda x} \right]_0^2 \\
&= 1-e^{-2 \lambda} \approx  0.865 \ \text{if}  \ \lambda = 1
\end{align*}

Note that since $\mathbb P(X=2) = 0$ we have $\mathbb P(X \leq 2 ) = \mathbb P(X<2)$.

Comment: Correct, but since $\mathbb P(X<0)=0$ I think it is fine to just write
$$
\mathbb P(X\leqslant 2) = \int_0^2 \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\ \mathsf dx.
$$

Comment: @Math1000
So for similar tasks I only have to change values in integral? For example $P(X\leq 5)=\int_{0}^{5}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$.
How about greater? $P(X\geq2)=\int_{2}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$? Between $P(2\leq X \leq 4)=\int_{2}^{4}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$